# User Control vs Pages vs Window on WPF Browser Applications

Tags: wpf, web-applications, browser, html, user-controls

Do you know what is the difference between: **User Control**, **Pages** and **Windows** on WPF Browser Applications. I've found information related with this, but all the time are about WPF Desktop application.

Is it different for WPF Browser application?
I'm deploying an application but I don't know what is the best option for the Login section, the main section, the about section, etc.

Could someone explain me how can I use this tools in WPF Browser application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Pages` in XBAPs the exact same way I would use a `Window` object in WPF. That is to say, rarely.

I usually have one Page/Window for my application and that is it. Switching the current view is usually done by switching a `CurrentView` property in my `ApplicationViewModel`, which changes what View is displayed in the main page.

I use `UserControls` when I want to create some kind of generic control, or for my `Views`. My `Views` can also be `DataTemplates`, and it is not uncommon for me to have a UserControl View that also has other Views in the `UserControl.Resources` (providing that all Views are related)

For example, I might have a UserControl called `ProductsView` which is the View that displays a list of `Product` objects, and the `UserControl.Resources` will contain a DataTemplate called `ProductView` which defines how WPF should display the `ProductModel`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rachel.This is exactly what I was searching.